# UISwipeGesture is not working on the view which listens touchesBegan

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using a star rating control.

https://github.com/erndev/EDStarRating

What I need is, when the user swipe left on that controller, a method is fired. There fore I added a swipe gesture on that view.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHappened)];
gesture.direction  = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

But I guess, the controller's touch recognizers cancels that swipe gesture recognizer.

So where am I wron? What can I do?

Comment: show ur code for touch recogniztion

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Comment: Are you adding it to your base view controller or some other view that is already overlayed? We need more context to help

Comment: I am adding it to the EDStarRatingView in a view controller's viewDidLoad after EDStarRatingView is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If it has other gesture recognizers on it, make your controller be the swipe gesture's delegate and return `YES` for `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`

Answer (score 0):

All Gestures provided in iOS are just a wrapper on touches and drag events only.

I. If you have touch events delegates present on your view then gestures identification will not work on that same view.

II. If you have a child view on base view and base view is having touche events delegates present and you want to implement gestures on a child view then you can do it, only you have to tell that implemented gesture that to cancel the touches available on it due to base view. This you can achieve using **cancelTouchesInView** method on a gesture.
If you are in second case, then add below line in your gesture implementation code.

```
gesture.cancelTouchedInView = YES;
```